# Mod_rewrite all request to subdirectory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all of the requests to my website www.example.com/page.php to www.example.com/1/page.php (where page.php is any page request), but I am new to mod_rewrite and cannot figure out how to do this.

What would be the rewrite_rule and/or conditions to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /1/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I didn't test it, but it must work

Comment: How can this be modified to only redirect if the folder isn't already included? E.g. "/1/anything" should not redirect but "/anything" should.

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^page.php$ 1/page.php [NC,L]
```

this can go in your htaccess file but will only redirect requests to page.php