# Create Apache mod rewrite rule to process all request to subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect all incoming requests to a subdirectory, but can't figure out how. I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431195/mod-rewrite-all-request-to-subdirectory) but that did not work for me.

So, if someone visits `www.example.com/test`, I want it to redirect to: `www.example.com/test/subdirectory`, but the URL still needs to be `www.example.com/test`

I also need the parameters to work, for example `www.example.com/test/index.php?action=home` must redirect to `www.example.com/test/subdirectory/index.php?action=home`.

I hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in fact what you ask for is not a redirect.

A redirect means the web server will send a new url containing the subdirectory, the browser will then request this new url, and show it in the url bar of the browser.

What you want is to tranparently map an directory structure to a real directory structure which differs. This is what Apache can do easily with the `Alias` instruction. Mod-rewrite could also do that, with RewriteRules not containing the `[R]` tag, this would imply an internal rewrite, not a redirect HTTP response. A `[QSA]` tag would also tell mod-rewrite to keep the current query string parameters on the rewritten url. But Mod-rewrite is not always simple to understand, and your problem is simple enough for a basic [`Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias), which is almost always included in Apache (more often than mod-rewrite).

this should be ok:

```
Alias /test /test/subdirectory
```

Comment: Hi regilero, Thank you for your answer, really appreciate it! I did not know the existence of the Alias. I marked your answer as the correct answer to my question. Now I receive the error: Alias not allowed here. But I think that is due a permission setting of my hosting.

Comment: The `Alias` directive cannot be used in a `.htaccess` file. It needs to be either in the main server config or your virtual host.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to the .htaccess file in the root directory of your site.
Query string parameters are passed through by default.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if not an existing file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# rewrite to subdirectory
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/[^/]+)?$ /$1/subdirectory/$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi Ulrich Palha. Thank you for your anwers!